# Centos mysql version is 5.5 however PHPmyadmin still says version 5.1

Tags: centos, mysql

When i run the following in my console:

```
[root@****~]# mysql -u root -p -e 'SELECT VERSION();'
Enter password:
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.5.39    |
+-----------+
```

Which should be the correct version.

However when i enter my PHPMYADMIN on my server it has the following specs:

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Program: MySQL
Programversion: 5.1.73 - Source distribution
```

So which version is the correct one and how do i make sure that the database is running on 5.5?

**Note**

I have already restarted sql several times without any changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mysqld is definitely running MySQL 5.5.39

to make sure please run

```
mysqld --version | awk '{print $3}'
```

PHPMyadmin might be using a 5.1.73 client

You could also login to mysql from the command line and run this

```
mysql> status
```

You will get output resembling this

```
/usr/bin/mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.30, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Connection id:          723
Current database:       mydb
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          '...'
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.5.30-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    utf8
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
UNIX socket:            /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Uptime:                 10 hours 40 min 45 sec

Threads: 5  Questions: 820429  Slow queries: 79  Opens: 4376  Flush tables: 3 ...
```

You will see the line

```
Server version:         5.5.30-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

It is the server version that matters.

Line 1 has the client version.

- If it says 5.1.73, just install the 5.5.39 client and remove the 5.1.73 client.
- If it says 5.5.39, and PHPMyAdmin still insists that it's 5.1.73, you may have two installed clients and PHPMyAdmin is stubbornly using the old one. Just uninstall the 5.1.73 client.